# How to show this sequence is in $l^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $\{a_k\}$ is a sequence such that for any sequence $\{b_k\}$in $l^q$ series $\sum_k a_k b_k$ is convergent, then how to show $a_k$ is in $l^p$ where $\infty>p,q>1$ and $1/p+1/q=1$.

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249454/prove-that-for-the-series-sum-n-in-mathbbn-zeta-n-mu-n-to-be-converge/2249604#2249604

Comment: $Mark Absolute convergence is not needed. I have used just convergence in my answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It is automatically the case that in a finite dimensional Banach space, every convergent series is also absolutely convergent.

Comment: @Mark Is $\sum  \frac {(-1)^{n}} n$ absolutely convergent? You are right in saying that $\sum a_k b_k$ automatically converges absolutely (because we can replace $b_k$ by $b_k c_k$ with suitable $c_k$'s with $|c_k|=1$ but finite dimensionality is not the argument.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I was reading here where it said that finite dimensionality is needed: https://books.google.com/books?id=lgmzFuMy09QC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22in+a+Banach+space+every+convergent+series+is+absolutely+convergent+iff+the+space+is+finite+dimensional+%22&source=bl&ots=EBH5VzPMKx&sig=E41pLmZfdXhnY8_Jco8QgPSnf2s&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22in%20a%20Banach%20space%20every%20convergent%20series%20is%20absolutely%20convergent%20iff%20the%20space%20is%20finite%20dimensional%20%22&f=false%20finite%20dimensional%20%22&f=false

Comment: @Kavi This is still essentially the same question, since $b_k$ can always be chosen to have $a_kb_k = |a_k b_k|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $T_n:l^{q}\to \mathbb C$ by $T_n \{b_k\}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k b_k$. If we show that $||T_n||=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k|^{p})^{1/p}$ we can finish the proof using Uniform boundedness principle. From now on I will take all sums from $1$ to $n$. It is easy to see that $||T_n||\leq (\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k|^{p})^{1/p}$ . Let $b_k=\frac {|a_k|^{p}} {a_k}$ if $a_k \neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise. Note that $\sum |b_k|^{q}=\sum |a_k|^{(p-1)q}=\sum |a_k|^{p}$. Hence $||T_n|| \geq \frac {|T_n \{b_k\}|} {(\sum |a_k|^{p})^{1/q}}$. But $T_n \{b_k\}=\sum |a_k|^{p}$. Can you take it from here?